# Where can I find a list of companies that aggressively sue over copyright infringement?

Tags: copyright

I am hoping to find a list of companies that aggressively sue or have sued over copyright infringement. For example, a quick Google search shows a number of lawsuits by Disney.

Does anyone know where to find such a list?

Comment: Since there is no way to define "aggressively suing", there is no such list. More generally, there is no list of entities who have filed a copyright infringement lawsuit.

Answer (score 2):

There are many ways to define "aggressively suing," and there are lists of entities that have filed copyright infringement actions.

Lex Machina probably maintains the most comprehensive data on the subject, so I'd recommend starting there. I believe their [most recent report](http://pages.lexmachina.com/Copyright-Litigation-Report-Registration.html) is freely available with registration (and probably some annoying phone solicitations). If you just want to get a snapshot of the top names in the game, you could just pull up some news coverage of the report. I was able to quickly find coverage of different iterations from [TorrentFreak](https://torrentfreak.com/adult-movie-outfit-is-most-litigious-copyright-plaintiff-in-u-s-150812/) and [Law360](https://www.law360.com/articles/1036945/the-firms-filing-the-most-copyright-suits).